# Assignment in conditional expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i get some error here and i don't now why ?

Code:

```
confirm("Estas listo para jugar ? ");
var edad = prompt("Cuantos años tienes ?");
if (edad <= 18){
    console.log("Puedes jugar, pero solo bajo tu propia responsabilidad");
} else {
    console.log("Animate a jugar ahora mismo !!");
}

console.log("Bienvenido a esta gran historia, ahora podras escuchar de todo y ver de todo. A continuacion ...");
console.log("Blancanieves y Batman estaban en el paradero de bus, esperando para poder ir de compras. Había una venta de liquidación, y ambos necesitaban comprar prendas nuevas. Batman nunca te cayó bien. Caminas hacia él.");
console.log("Batman te mira con odio.");
var userAnswer = prompt("¿Te crees muy de buenas, idiota?");
if (userAnswer = Si){
    console.log("Batman te golpea bien fuerte. ¡Él es Batman, y tú eres tú! ¡Pero claro que Batman te ganaría!");
} else {
    console.log("Decidiste que no te sientes con suerte. ¡Bien hecho! Haz ganado el juego de evitar que Batman te rompa la cara");
}
```

This is where everything starts to fail:

```
var userAnswer = prompt("¿Te crees muy de buenas, idiota?");
```

and I write everything I get: `Batman te golpea bien fuerte. ¡Él es Batman, y tú eres tú! ¡Pero claro que Batman te ganaría!`. When I press `Si` or `no`, Example, the first

```
if (edad <= 18){  // works 

if (userAnswer = Si){ //does not work
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `Si` to `userAnswer` not comparing.

```
 if (userAnswer = Si){
```

should be

```
 if (userAnswer == 'Si'){
```

**Update**

Also your Si should be in quotes like `'Si'` when you are comparing user's input with string.

About operator

```
= is an assignment operator

== is a comparison  operator
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but whe i write this i dont get the same eror i get another like : ReferenceError: Si is not defined why if (edad <= 18){ working but in this second i get this error

Comment: From where you are getting the value into `Si`? It should be defined with some value did you this?

Comment: what makes you a confused?

Comment: I am learning here http://www.codecademy.com, but i can't understand, never explain me about these error in the tutorial

Comment: Before you compare, the `Si` should have any value, like `var Si = 15;`

Comment: In the codeacademy say me to make a simple history with if /else, i don't now to define a value, i mean var value = value i think thats it

Comment: Yes but i can't put var Si = 15; i need var Si = Si;

Comment: Can you tell me one thing what `Si`?

Comment: Si mean Yes, when the player asked " YOU THINK YOU ARE GOOD ? " , player should say Yes

Comment: oh..the Si should be into quotes like `'Si'` like `(userAnswer == 'Si')`, have a look updated answer also.

Comment: OMG man you are MAGICIAN Thank you very much, I love you, but i need t o ask you '= is an assignment operator' << this mean assignment is only for number ? because in the 'if (edad <= 18){  // works ' because was a number and now '== is a comparison  operator' comparison is only for letters ? because only with Yes work + "" :)

Comment: `<=` is also comparision operator, you can use this for compare  both string or number, Assignment `=` operator is different thing, it is used to assign the value like `var name = "Rock"`; which means 'rock' is assigning to variable `name`

Comment: I found you are new to Stackoverflow, If you find this answer is useful, please click on the tick mark as a accepted answer.

Comment: I acepted , thanks again, but i can't give points because requires 15 reputation